# Converting MSSQL Dump to MySQL Dump on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, export, import, ms-sql

I only have Ubuntu to work with, so Windows programs are not going to work for me. But basically I have both the .bak file and the .sql file from a MSSQL server and I need to import this data into a new MySQL server.

I can't use the MySQL Workbench migration tools (I think) because I don't have actual access to the MSSQL database. What tools exist to convert the file in a format that I can use with MySQL workbench? Any suggestion is welcome, including something like converting to a .csv and then importing that, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the best way that I could find was to restore the DB from the *.bak into a SQL server in a Windows Virtual Box using the evaluation version of the SQL Server. After that, I used MySQL Workbench to migrate the data from one database to the other and boom, all the data was now in my MySQL database.